# How do I evaluate correlation of model parameters using MCMC posterior samples from a rstan fit?

Tags: r, correlation, posterior, stan

Is there a better way to do so than simply by taking posterior parameter estimates and calculating the Spearman or Pearson correlation between them? Anything specific to having posterior samples from RStan?

Comment: Do you have an example of the code that you're using? The answer is to simply include the correlations you're interested in as a parameter to be estimated as well. That's relatively easy to do, but with model code, it could be possible to show how it can be adjusted to incorporate that correlation. Alternatively, you could always include the calculation of the correlation coefficients in the generated quantities block of the code, saving you from having to extract the posterior draws and calculate the correlation from there